# Generate HTML documentation for a FreeMarker FTL library

Tags: documentation-generation, freemarker

I've a FreeMarker library that I want to ship with my product, and I'm looking for a way to generate a HTML documentation for it based on the comments in the FTL file (in a Javadoc fashion).

For example, a typical function in my library is written like:

```
<#--
  MyMacro: Does stuff with param1 and param2.
  - param1: The first param, mandatory.
  - param2: The second param, 42 if not specified.
-->
<#macro MyMacro param1 param2=42>
  ...
</#macro>
```

I didn't find anything on that subject, probably because there is no standard way of writing comments in FreeMarker (Such as `@param` or `@returns` in Javadoc).

I don't mind rolling my own solution for that, but I'm keen on using an existing system like Doxia (since I'm using Maven to build the project) or Doxygen maybe, instead of writing something from scratch.
Ideally I'd like to write the comment parsing code only, and rely on something else to detect the macros and generate the doc structure.

I'm open to changing the format of my comments if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you decide to write your own doc generator or to write a FTL-specific front-end for an existing document generator, you can reuse some of FreeMarker's parsing infrastructure:

You can use `Template.getRootTreeNode()` in order to retrieve the template's top level AST node. Because macros and the responding comments should be direct children of the this top level node (IIRC), iterating over its children and casting them to the right AST node subclass should give you almost everything you need with respect to FTL syntax. To illustrate the approach I hacked together a little "demo" (`cfg` is a normal FreeMarker `Configuration` object):

```
Template t = cfg.getTemplate("foo.ftl");
TemplateElement te = t.getRootTreeNode();

Enumeration e = te.children();
while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
    Object child = e.nextElement();
    if(child instanceof Comment) {
        Comment comment = (Comment)child;
        System.out.println("COMMENT: " + comment.getText());
    } else if(child instanceof Macro) {
        Macro macro = (Macro)child;
        System.out.println("MACRO: " + macro.getName());
        for(String argumentName : macro.getArgumentNames()) {
            System.out.println("- PARAM: " + argumentName);
        }
    }
}
```

produces for your given example macro:

```
COMMENT: 
  MyMacro: Does stuff with param1 and param2.
  - param1: The first param, mandatory.
  - param2: The second param, 42 if not specified.

MACRO: MyMacro
- PARAM: param1
- PARAM: param2
```

How you parse the comment is then up to you ;-)

**Update**: Found something called `ftldoc` in my backups and [uploaded it to GitHub](https://github.com/chaquotay/ftldoc). Maybe this is what you are looking for...

Comment: This all sounded somewhat familiar, as if I did something similar many years ago, so I googled and searched through my backups and indeed found an old project of mine called `ftldoc` which generates HTML documentation for FTL files. I'll upload it somewhere (maybe GitHub?) and post a link here :-)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for, I even might fork it and add new features :)